# @user.posts.where('status = ?', :unfinished).all returns []

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

By `@user.posts`, I can see there is a post with :unfinished status.

But `@user.posts.where('status = ?', :unfinished).all` returns an empty array.

I've tried to invoke `@user.reload` first, but it doesn't resolve the problem.

```
(rdb:568) @user.posts
[#<Post id: 1, content: "hehe", user_id: 1, created_at: "2010-04-03 06:16:47", updated_at: "2010-04-03 06:16:47", status: "--- :unfinished\n">]

(rdb:568) @user.posts.where('status = ?', :unfinished).all
[]
```

**update:**

Oh, I see. Rails doesn't escape :unfinished well, it missing the closing '

`status = '--- :unfinished\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@user.posts.where('status = :status',{:status => 'unfinished'}).all`